# unable to call repaint from inner class

Tags: java, swing

I have a outer class which extends JPanel and holds a paintComponent method which just draws an image, my inner class is also a JPanel and is my mouse event listener. The events change the way the drawing looks by calling the repaint after the changed, but it doesn't seem like the repaint is getting called properly

```
    public class FollowingEyes extends JPanel
{
    private Eye eye;
    private Eye eye2;
    private final int HEIGHT = 500;
    private final int WIDTH = 500;
    private OtherPanel panel;
    public FollowingEyes()
    {

        eye     =   new Eye((WIDTH/2)-50,50);
        eye2    =   new Eye((WIDTH/2)+50,50);     
        panel   =   new OtherPanel();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
       addMouseListener(panel);
       addMouseMotionListener(panel);
    }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        eye.draw(g);
        eye2.draw(g);              
    }



    private class OtherPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
    { 



           @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Mouse entered..");
            eye.look(true);
            eye2.look(true);
            repaint();

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Mouse exited..");
            eye.look(false);
            eye2.look(false);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){};
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){};
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){};

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            eye.setAngle(e.getX(), e.getY());
            eye2.setAngle(e.getX(), e.getY());
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){};


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, the field `eyes` is unused therefore unessecary. Also, if you want to call the repaint on the whole `FollowingEyes` from `OtherPanel`, use `FollowingEyes.this.repaint()`. What you currently have is repainting *only* `OtherPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your eyes (`eye` and `eye2`) are added to the `FollowingEyes` panel but when mouse is moved, you call `repaint()` on the `OtherPanel` thus eyes will not be repainted.

Try calling `repaint()` of the `FollowingEyes` instance:

```
eyes.repaint();
```

Also another problem is that the `eyes` attribute of `OtherPanel` is initialized with a new `FollowingEyes` instance and not with the enclosing instance. You should initialize it with `FollowingEyes.this` or pass it as a constructor argument (that way you will be able to make the `OtherPanel` class an external class).

Comment: Thanks, sorry to cause confusion with the eyes field - wasn't supposed to be there.